# Swiper with custom widths

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I'm trying to create a specific slider using Swiper (https://swiperjs.com/). For example, I want my slide to have width of 300px and when it becomes active to have width of 700px.. I'm setting the widths with CSS and for slidesPerView I'm using 'auto'. Is there a way to achieve this? I'm trying with on slideChange event to run the following swiper functions without any luck - swiper.updateProgress(), swiper.updateSize(), swiper.update() and swiper.updateSlides().. Any other suggestions I could try?

Answer (score 0):

When a slide is active, it recieves a new class named "swiper-slide-active".
You can change the CSS of this class. Example:

```
.swiper-slide-active {
    width: 700px !important;
}
```

If you want to set the width of your slider, just alter the css of the marked container (see picture below)
[image]

I hope this was helpful, if I missunderstood your question, feel free to ask again :).

Comment: Yeah, I know that.. For swiper-slide I have width: 300px, while for swiper-slide-active I have 700px. But that creates a problem since swiper uses trasnlate3d to display the slides and it's not translating with the active slide width, it just translate it with 300px, there fore the second slide is cut in half.